# A good laptop with two dvi outputs?

Tags: laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Laptop that supports 2 external monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/177427/laptop-that-supports-2-external-monitors)

Are there laptops capable of driving two 1920x1200 screens (with rotation)?

Comment: Dupe maybe? http://superuser.com/questions/177427/laptop-that-supports-2-external-monitors.  Rotation is normally a driver feature.

Comment: Is DVI a requirement? Why not USB for the 2nd?

Comment: i have a usb video card now;  i'm just tired of the setup -- i want a laptop that can drive 3 monitors (including itself)

Comment: I had a response dealing with VGA and DVI outs. Just deleted it though -- hadn't noticed the "two DVI" part of your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Dell Latitude with E Port Plus docking station for two DVI outputs and make sure you get the NVIDIA graphics card for supporting rotation

E Port Plus:
http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/Docking_Station/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&cs=19&sku=430-3312

Also features Display Port

EDIT: Noticed in your comment you want to run two externals AND the laptop display... you may be able to accomplish this with the Display Port option, but not DVI. It's a limitation of the video cards and the number of streams they support. Display Port runs differently, I've heard the monitor does more of the stream splitting? I'm not very clear though.